# MySQL Limit Results Based on Join Table

Tags: mysql, sql, many-to-many

I have 2 tables,but linked in many to many relations so 3 tables :

```
Table Author :
idAuthor,
Name 

+----------+-------+
| idAuthor | Name  |
+----------+-------+
|        1 | Renee |
|        2 | John  |
|        3 | Bob   |
|        4 | Bryan |
+----------+-------+
Table Publication:
idPublication,
Title,
Type,
Date,
Journal,
Conference

+---------------+--------------+------+-------------+------------+-----------+
| idPublication | Title        | Date | Type        | Conference | Journal   |
+---------------+--------------+------+-------------+------------+-----------+
|             1 | Flower thing | 2008 | book        | NULL       | NULL      |
|             2 | Bees         | 2009 | article     | NULL       | Le Monde  |
|             3 | Wasps        | 2010 | inproceding | KDD        | NULL      |
|             4 | Whales       | 2010 | inproceding | DPC        | NULL      |
|             5 | Lyon         | 2011 | article     | NULL       | Le Figaro |
|             6 | Plants       | 2012 | book        | NULL       | NULL      |
+---------------+--------------+------+-------------+------------+-----------+
Table author_has_publication :
Author_idAuthor,
Publication_idPublication

+-----------------+---------------------------+
| Author_idAuthor | Publication_idPublication |
+-----------------+---------------------------+
|               1 |                         1 |
|               2 |                         2 |
|               3 |                         3 |
|               4 |                         4 |
|               1 |                         5 |
|               2 |                         5 |
|               3 |                         5 |
|               3 |                         6 |
+-----------------+---------------------------+
```

What I want to do is get the top X author having the most publications.

I achieved to get the result avec the idAuthor having the most publications, using this request :
`SELECT Author_idAuthor, COUNT(*) as count FROM Author_has_publication GROUP BY Author_idAuthor ORDER BY count DESC;`
I get the list of the authors id, ordered by the number of publications :

```
+-----------------+-------+
| Author_idAuthor | count |
+-----------------+-------+
|               3 |     3 |
|               2 |     2 |
|               1 |     2 |
|               4 |     1 |
+-----------------+-------+
```

but then when I try to select the author corresponding to the top X of the result set of the previous query I have an error
I am Trying this `SELECT TOP 2 FROM author WHERE (SELECT Author_idAuthor, COUNT(*) as count FROM Author_has_publication GROUP BY Author_idAuthor ORDER BY count DESC)=idAuthor;`
I think it might be because my inside query return 2 rows, and I do a simple `SELECT` here or that I need a `JOIN` but i have no ideas how to use it here.

Comment: Share some sample input and output. It would be easier to help. Besides, I guess, you are having issues to show the names of the author.

Comment: I edited as you asked

Comment: Are you using Sql or MySQL? Try the below query given by @Alan Hay. See if it works.

Comment: I am using MySQL 5.7 command line client, and I tried it already :(

Comment: The query you showed returns the total count and id of the author. Now you want the name with it. Am I correct? MySQL uses LIMIT, not TOP.

Comment: Yes, but when I tried Alan query I got an satement saying my MySQL doesn't support Limit, (i put a comment with the exact statement)

Comment: Try using INNER JOIN with author id in the query.

Comment: Alan resolved it, I am trying to understand now, it is same mechanism as a join isn't it ?

Comment: I was sure about Alan's solution. Yes, same as JOIN.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MySQL has no TOP keyword. It does however have a LIMIT keyword. Your query is invalid anyway.

There are a couple of options here. The following is an example of a correlated subquery: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Correlated_subquery

```
SELECT 
    a.idAuthor, 
    a.Name , 
    (SELECT COUNT(*) from author_has_publication ahp WHERE   
        ahp.Author_idAuthor = a.idAuthor) AS publication_count
FROM 
    author a
ORDER BY 
    publication_count DESC
LIMIT 2
```

As the referenced article notes, the above is inefficient as the subquery needs to be re-executed for each row of the result. If you do not actually need the count in the resultset then the below would be more efficient as the subquery is non-correlated and executed only once.

```
SELECT 
    a.idAuthor, 
    a.Name 
FROM 
    author a
INNER JOIN 
    (select ahp.Author_idAuthor AS idAuthor, COUNT(*) as publication_count 
        FROM author_has_publication ahp GROUP BY ahp.Author_idAuthor LIMIT 2) 
        AS TEMP ON TEMP.idAuthor = a.idAuthor
```

Comment: it says that my version of MySQL doesn't support 'LIMIT & IN/ALL/ANY/SOME subquery'

Comment: Yes, you are correct. See updated answer which uses an inline select.

Comment: It works thanks ! It is the same mechanism as a join you just did ?

Comment: The first answer attempted to use an IN clause with SUBSELECT which (looks like what you were trying to do) but didn't work as no support for LIMIT. See the example 'MySQL IN with subquery' here: http://www.mysqltutorial.org/sql-in.aspx

Comment: The accepted answer uses a CORRELATED SUBQUERY within the select clause. See here for details and performance issues https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Correlated_subquery